# Application automatically redirect to login page during postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, iis-8

In Asp.net application, it automatically redirect to the login page. It happens when i select a drop down and it raise postback to fill the other dropdown. At that time it happens again and again.. Below are the steps i follow to replicate this behavior:

- Login to the website.
- Go to this webpage which causing problem.
- This page has a pre filled dropdown. Select this drop down which generates a postback.
- If it does not redirect to the login page then other dropdown redirect to the login page

There was no exception or error screen display for this scenario. Is there any programmer fault needs to be corrected or server issue.

IIS Log:

```
+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 __AntiXsrfToken=ce431a91a91943169e22c320b914cd20;+.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=JxKIhhhPqKTi90ZXk8hmaK7KL4Aeb9ORhpnKdXYp_3zmwh2hcWgC9c2ej1Uw8N-YgVhXXKNvgszx-RQT2widCDgt99pXmzetPcQa841DceWmkBJ8cPN9eG56Cw5gf3TFZZJg1pj0tEbZ0Rr8sVHoklWRsgPkT0TP4HQP7cVhVGgiNvySIYKebWZIpR24u0cjkXz9Wtjr06cb29IegBDnrVCCIfIovoVPpleV1wcG02pRSaVnygsqcXlrB1FB9jrtDAMah5PQowc7CxB0RXMTeDJpPQvciVAJ5X7RDgYAcMZ7axcsWPPaeGX1DfGum1gXdAgvfz5SYkYWFVQM285wj2iWJIMeZmZUo1YokcYRraBE_5ewW1qrd4n_77ex9mD8oiJtFj3w8f5_FA6bW64-zQLzFcz4Ca9fcLfh2uQ-YOhi4o0itUW-A_bEIPVWX3eVPUSK8-pZo6q_FpdAQJbUT1lgpr7fIYiWQwEXmxBq0DjJEnJMTX0LCOP0TpJma5Fwwd8bYr3dFqifUreoJK-iZA http://stellarvendor.com/Users/ProductEntry stellarvendor.com 200 0 0 90250 20432 24880
2016-08-11 20:18:32 W3SVC2957 GET /Users/ProductEntry - - 103.55.89.240 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 __AntiXsrfToken=ce431a91a91943169e22c320b914cd20;+.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=JxKIhhhPqKTi90ZXk8hmaK7KL4Aeb9ORhpnKdXYp_3zmwh2hcWgC9c2ej1Uw8N-YgVhXXKNvgszx-RQT2widCDgt99pXmzetPcQa841DceWmkBJ8cPN9eG56Cw5gf3TFZZJg1pj0tEbZ0Rr8sVHoklWRsgPkT0TP4HQP7cVhVGgiNvySIYKebWZIpR24u0cjkXz9Wtjr06cb29IegBDnrVCCIfIovoVPpleV1wcG02pRSaVnygsqcXlrB1FB9jrtDAMah5PQowc7CxB0RXMTeDJpPQvciVAJ5X7RDgYAcMZ7axcsWPPaeGX1DfGum1gXdAgvfz5SYkYWFVQM285wj2iWJIMeZmZUo1YokcYRraBE_5ewW1qrd4n_77ex9mD8oiJtFj3w8f5_FA6bW64-zQLzFcz4Ca9fcLfh2uQ-YOhi4o0itUW-A_bEIPVWX3eVPUSK8-pZo6q_FpdAQJbUT1lgpr7fIYiWQwEXmxBq0DjJEnJMTX0LCOP0TpJma5Fwwd8bYr3dFqifUreoJK-iZA - stellarvendor.com 302 0 0 2579 943 5387
2016-08-11 20:18:34 W3SVC2957 POST /Users/ProductEntry - - 103.55.89.240 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 __AntiXsrfToken=ce431a91a91943169e22c320b914cd20;+.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=JxKIhhhPqKTi90ZXk8hmaK7KL4Aeb9ORhpnKdXYp_3zmwh2hcWgC9c2ej1Uw8N-YgVhXXKNvgszx-RQT2widCDgt99pXmzetPcQa841DceWmkBJ8cPN9eG56Cw5gf3TFZZJg1pj0tEbZ0Rr8sVHoklWRsgPkT0TP4HQP7cVhVGgiNvySIYKebWZIpR24u0cjkXz9Wtjr06cb29IegBDnrVCCIfIovoVPpleV1wcG02pRSaVnygsqcXlrB1FB9jrtDAMah5PQowc7CxB0RXMTeDJpPQvciVAJ5X7RDgYAcMZ7axcsWPPaeGX1DfGum1gXdAgvfz5SYkYWFVQM285wj2iWJIMeZmZUo1YokcYRraBE_5ewW1qrd4n_77ex9mD8oiJtFj3w8f5_FA6bW64-zQLzFcz4Ca9fcLfh2uQ-YOhi4o0itUW-A_bEIPVWX3eVPUSK8-pZo6q_FpdAQJbUT1lgpr7fIYiWQwEXmxBq0DjJEnJMTX0LCOP0TpJma5Fwwd8bYr3dFqifUreoJK-iZA http://stellarvendor.com/Users/ProductEntry stellarvendor.com 302 0 0 2579 20661 3326
2016-08-11 20:18:43 W3SVC2957 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FUsers%2FProductEntry - 103.55.89.240 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 __AntiXsrfToken=ce431a91a91943169e22c320b914cd20;+.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=JxKIhhhPqKTi90ZXk8hmaK7KL4Aeb9ORhpnKdXYp_3zmwh2hcWgC9c2ej1Uw8N-YgVhXXKNvgszx-RQT2widCDgt99pXmzetPcQa841DceWmkBJ8cPN9eG56Cw5gf3TFZZJg1pj0tEbZ0Rr8sVHoklWRsgPkT0TP4HQP7cVhVGgiNvySIYKebWZIpR24u0cjkXz9Wtjr06cb29IegBDnrVCCIfIovoVPpleV1wcG02pRSaVnygsqcXlrB1FB9jrtDAMah5PQowc7CxB0RXMTeDJpPQvciVAJ5X7RDgYAcMZ7axcsWPPaeGX1DfGum1gXdAgvfz5SYkYWFVQM285wj2iWJIMeZmZUo1YokcYRraBE_5ewW1qrd4n_77ex9mD8oiJtFj3w8f5_FA6bW64-zQLzFcz4Ca9fcLfh2uQ-YOhi4o0itUW-A_bEIPVWX3eVPUSK8-pZo6q_FpdAQJbUT1lgpr7fIYiWQwEXmxBq0DjJEnJMTX0LCOP0TpJma5Fwwd8bYr3dFqifUreoJK-iZA - stellarvendor.com 200 0 0 8333 972 11390
2016-08-11 20:18:50 W3SVC2957 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FUsers%2FProductEntry - 103.55.89.240 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 __AntiXsrfToken=ce431a91a91943169e22c320b914cd20;+.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=JxKIhhhPqKTi90ZXk8hmaK7KL4Aeb9ORhpnKdXYp_3zmwh2hcWgC9c2ej1Uw8N-YgVhXXKNvgszx-RQT2widCDgt99pXmzetPcQa841DceWmkBJ8cPN9eG56Cw5gf3TFZZJg1pj0tEbZ0Rr8sVHoklWRsgPkT0TP4HQP7cVhVGgiNvySIYKebWZIpR24u0cjkXz9Wtjr06cb29IegBDnrVCCIfIovoVPpleV1wcG02pRSaVnygsqcXlrB1FB9jrtDAMah5PQowc7CxB0RXMTeDJpPQvciVAJ5X7RDgYAcMZ7axcsWPPaeGX1DfGum1gXdAgvfz5SYkYWFVQM285wj2iWJIMeZmZUo1YokcYRraBE_5ewW1qrd4n_77ex9mD8oiJtFj3w8f5_FA6bW64-zQLzFcz4Ca9fcLfh2uQ-YOhi4o0itUW-A_bEIPVWX3eVPUSK8-pZo6q_FpdAQJbUT1lgpr7fIYiWQwEXmxBq0DjJEnJMTX0LCOP0TpJma5Fwwd8bYr3dFqifUreoJK-iZA http://stellarvendor.com/Users/ProductEntry stellarvendor.com 200 0 0 8333 1128 7040
```

Note: This is he behaviour on the Shared Hosting but on local IIS it is working fine in every expect. I am not able to figure out that what is wrong on another IIS environment.

Comment: Does that user have permission to access `/Users/ProductEntry`? Can you show some code?

Comment: Yes. it has. User are authorized to access this folder items. It is working fine on local IIS and visual studio debug environment.

Comment: Could you take out Anti-XSRF token and try again *(I would like to see Anti-XSRF causes the issue)*?

Comment: Ok.. I will give it a try but it will create security issues.